# Economy hotel chains in China

Tags: budget, china, hotels

I am looking for domestic brands of economy hotels in China that are similar to, say, [Ibis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibis_(hotel)) in Europe (i.e. roughly in the 3-star range). I would expect them to have locations in most medium-size and large cities, to maintain similar standards (simple, safe, clean, with WiFi, with some English-speaking staff members, etc.) at all locations, to offer convenient locations (e.g. close to train stations) and also a single platform for Internet booking, and to cater both to businesspeople and (domestic as well as international) tourists.

Are there any such brands that come to mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jin Jiang hotels or 168 are decent low priced hotels in China, there is also 268 and some others

Jin Jiang have multiple brands all the way from very cheap to 5 star properties so that’s properly the best start for you to look

Comment: By now I have come across a list of Chinese travel businesses (in a German language [newspaper article](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/coronavirus-besorgt-die-wirtschaft-in-china-16593256.html) about the looming impact of the new virus outbreak on the Chinese economy) that includes Jin Jiang and provides good starting points for my purposes: "First Travel Hotel, Songcheng und Jinjiang Hotels".